# Why does "None in numpy.asarray(...)" cause a future warning

Tags: python, numpy, nan

The future warning happens when you do something like this:

```
>>> numpy.asarray([1,2,3,None]) == None
```

Which currently returns `False`, but I understand will return an array containing `[False,False,False,True]` in a future version of Numpy.

As discussed [on the numpy discussion list](http://lists.ipython.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-September/071235.html) the way around this is to test`a is None`.

What confuses me is this behaviour of the `in` keyword with a 1D array compared to a list:

```
>>> None in [1,2,3,None]
True
>>> None in numpy.asarray([1,2,3,None])
__main__:1: FutureWarning: comparison to 'None' will result in an elementwise 
    object comparison in the future
False
>>> 1 in numpy.asarray([1,2,3,None])
True
```

EDIT (see comments) - There are really two different questions:

1. Why does this cause a `FutureWarning` - what will the future behaviour of `None in numpy.asarray(...)` be compared to what it is now?
2. Why the difference in behaviour of `in` from a `list`; can I test if my array contains `None` without converting it to a list or using a `for` loop?

Numpy version is 1.9.1, Python 3.4.1

Comment: Why would your array contain `None`?  Look at the `dtype` of an example with `None`.  Is that what you want?  Are you, by any chance, confusing `None` with `np.nan`?

Comment: I am using data that could contain `None`. I know that `None` is not `np.nan`. My exact situation is more complicated than my example but that's not really relevant to the question.

Looking at the `dtype` does work though. Thanks.

Incidentally, `np.nan in np.asarray([1,2,3,np.nan])` will also return `False`. So maybe my question should be about `in` and numpy arrays in general.

Comment: Although, `dtype` will still be `object` if you take a slice from a matrix which has `None` in it, even if that slice doesn't have a `None` in it.

Comment: The question of `in` for arrays came up in another question recently.  It appears to work, but may actually be acting on `list(array...)`.  I don't think it is the right test for arrays.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.in1d`.  That seems to be the preferred array tester.  But it still has issues when it comes to testing `None` and `nan`.

Comment: It's clear that the `FutureWarning` and the `in` behaviour are probably different issues, although I'm also curious as to why `None in array` causes a `FutureWarning` as well as `array == None`.

Comment: @matches `np.nan in np.asarray([1,2,3,np.nan])` returns `False` because `np.nan != np.nan` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/1461210) for more details). What does a value of `None` *mean* in the context of your data? If you're using `None` to represent missing data, it would make much more sense to use `np.nan`, or better yet, switch to [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

Comment: Also, in future versions of numpy your example `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) == None` would return `np.array([False ,False, False, False])`. The new behaviour will be consistent with how element-wise comparisons to scalar numerical values currently work, e.g. `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1` returns  `np.array([True ,False, False, False])`

Comment: `np.nan != np.nan` and `np.nan in np.array([1,2,3,np.nan])` returns `False`... but `np.nan in [1,2,3,np.nan]` seems to return `True`. Strange.

Comment: masked arrays do look like they will solve my problem, however I still think a more detailed explanation of the behaviour of `in` on arrays might be of interest to someone, so I won't delete the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The future warning happens when you do something like this:
>
> ```
> numpy.asarray([1,2,3,4]) == None
> ```
>
> Which currently returns `False`, but I understand will return an array containing `[False,False,False,True]` in a future version of Numpy.

As I mentioned in the comments, your example is incorrect. Future versions of numpy would return `[False ,False, False, False]`, i.e. `False` for each element in the array that is not equal to `None`. This is more consistent with how element-wise comparisons to other scalar values currently work, e.g.:

```
In [1]: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) == 1
Out[1]: array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [2]: np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) == 'b'
Out[2]: array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

> What confuses me is this behaviour of the `in` keyword with a 1D array compared to a list

When you test `x in y`, you are calling `y.__contains__(x)`. When `y` is a list, `__contains__` basically does something along the lines of this:

```
for item in y:
    if (item is x) or (item == x):
        return True
return False
```

As far as I can tell, `np.ndarray.__contains__(x)` performs the equivalent of this:

```
if any(y == x):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

That is to say it tests element-wise equality over the whole array first (`y == x` would be a boolean array the size of `y`). Since in your case you are testing whether `y == None`, this will raise the `FutureWarning` for the reasons given above.

In the comments you also wanted to know why

```
np.nan in np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
```

returns `False`, but

```
np.nan in [1, 2, 3, np.nan]
```

returns `True`. The first part is easily explained by the fact that `np.nan != np.nan` ([see here for the rationale behind this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/1461210)). To understand why the second case returns `True`, remember that `list.__contains__()` first checks for identity (`is`) before checking equality (`==`). Since `np.nan is np.nan`, the second case will return `True`.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't notice my example was supposed to be `[1,2,3,None] == None` not `[1,2,3,4] == None` - I have corrected the question.